# Trying to get total amount based on user input

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a page where a user can submit a form, that works fine, but I want to have a quantity field where the user can input a number and in the totals box it will show the total as they update their quantity. I would like to achieve this without having to reload the page. I am thinking javascript would be the best to do this, but I am unsure of how to go about doing it as I have 0 experience with javascript. Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

My Code So Far:

```
    <form>
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" align="center"><img src="<?php echo getProductImage($product_id); ?>" title="<?php echo getProductName($product_id); ?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><br/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">Quantity:</td>
                <td colspan="2"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="number" min="64" max="9999" name="quantity" /></td>
                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;@&nbsp;&nbsp;$<?php echo number_format((getProductPrice($product_id)/2),4); ?>/per item&nbsp;&nbsp;=&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                <td>Total Goes Here</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: Well then, try googling ajax + jquery/javascript...

Comment: No need for Ajax if the prices are already loaded into the table. You may want to add an `attribute` like `data-product-price="PriceGoesHere"` on the `td` where you want to calculate the price (Total Goes Here) to make your life a bit easier since you have alot of `&nbsp;` and other clutter along with the price. E.g. `<td data-product-price="345.50">Total Goes Here</td>`

Comment: yeah I am just trying to mock it up right now and get it working then i will load it into my websites template where it will be alot cleaner.

Comment: I don't have a method to get the total price yet, that's what I was wondering how to make javascript or something get what is input into the `quantity` field and multiply it by `getProductPrice($product_id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/xkp3t9us/) JSFiddle (notice the added `data-product-price` attribute)

HTML

```
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">Quantity:</td>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="number" min="64" max="9999" name="quantity" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;@&nbsp;&nbsp;$345.50/per item&nbsp;&nbsp;=&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td data-product-price="345.50"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
$(function(){
    $("input[name='quantity']").on("input", function(){
        var $outputCell = $(this).parent().siblings("[data-product-price]").eq(0); 
        $outputCell.html((+$outputCell.data("product-price") * +$(this).val()).toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

Comment: No problem, i added functionality to check if inputted value is less than `min` or higher than `max` in this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/xkp3t9us/3/ If that is something you want to use

Comment: Wow!!! You went above and beyond my thinking and added in that extra functionality... it's just amazing thank you so much!!!

Comment: The only question is how to only show the dollars, not the cents. for some reason it is now showing results like 345.00 where i only need 345. I figured it out, just dropped the .toFixed(2)

Answer (score 0):

You could try by echo the price/per product inside a disabled input, or by adding an hidden input which value is the price/per product.

Then you can try this JS:

```
$('your_quantity_input').on('change', function() {
    var quantity = $(this).val();
    var price = $('your_hidden_input').val();
    var total = quantity * price;
    $('your_td_total').html(total);
});
```

This is by using jQuery.

Here is the working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/LzLep9ez/

Comment: so using this method what would i need to change in the form to display the results of this jquery?

Comment: this funciton is called everytime the quantity input changes. Inside the function it calculate the (new) quantity, multiply it for the price and then change the html inside the td with the result. You want me to add comments inside my answer?

Comment: I added your JS to the page but nothing happens when I reload it.

Comment: You have to change the selectors accordingly to your html

Answer (score 0):

A minimal example where jQuery and Javascript is used could be:

```html
<form>
  Quantity: <input type="text" id="quantityField">
  <div>Total: <span id="totalField">0</span> $ (5$/item)</div>
</form>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // The line above loads jQuery
  // Javascript code goes here. You would normally have this in a separate file.
  
  // Somehow fetch the desired price from your program
  var pricePerItem = 5;
  
  // This code executes when the quantityField elements value changes
  $('#quantityField').on('input',function(event){

    // 1. Read quantity
    var quantity = $(this).val();
    
    // 2. Calculate total
    var total = pricePerItem * quantity;
    
    // 3. Update total field
    $('#totalField').text(total);
    
  });
</script>
```

Note that this is a minimal example that does not follow best practises in programming javascript with regards to safety, code placement etc., but it might just help you on your way.