# Adding up rows of a column

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

After trying several things I found on the internet (none working) I cannot figure out how to add up a column in my table. I am trying to add up all the `Points` and print it out at the bottom where `Total` is located.

PHP Code:

```
<?php 

function getProducts() {
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM `oc_product` ORDER BY `model` ASC';
    $params = array();
    $results = dataQuery($query,$params);
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $product_id = $result['product_id'];
        $product_name = getProductName($product_id);
        $product_image = 'shop/image/'.$result['image'];
        $product_price = 1;
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td width="15px"><img src="'.$product_image.'" width="10px" height="10px" /></td>';
        echo '<td width="200px">'.$product_name.'</td>';
        echo '<td width="150px"><input type="number" value="0" min="0" max="3456" name="quantity" /></td>';
        echo '<td width="200px" align="center" data-product-price="'.$product_price.'">0</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}

function getProductName($product_id) {
    $query = 'SELECT `name` FROM `oc_product_description` WHERE `product_id` = ?';
    $params = array($product_id);
    $results = dataQuery($query,$params);
    return $results[0]['name'];
}

?>
```

Javascript Code:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("input[name='quantity']").on("input", function(){
        if((+$(this).val()) < (+$(this).attr("min"))){
            $(this).val($(this).attr("min"));
        } else if((+$(this).val()) > (+$(this).attr("max"))){
            $(this).val($(this).attr("max"));
        }

        var $outputCell = $(this).parent().siblings("[data-product-price]").eq(0); 
        $outputCell.html((+$outputCell.data("product-price") * +$(this).val()));
    });
});
</script>
```

The Form:

```
<form>
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="4"><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="In-Game Name" /><br/><br/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th align="center">Quantity</th>
            <th align="center">Points Earned</th>
        </tr>
        <?php echo getProducts(); ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><br/><br/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="right" colspan="3"><strong>Total:</strong></td>
            <td align="center">0 Points</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

--Edit--

Changed my code around and took out the javascript function `adding()` as it was old and didn't work. Now what would be the best way to add up all the cells in the column `Points Earned` and print it out in the last row where `Total` is located.

So if the total for each of the `Points Earned` is calculated via the `javascript code` how can one add that up and display it at the end of the table where `Total` is located?

Comment: where exactly is the issue? which column you are trying to add??

Comment: sorry about that I will edit my question

Comment: where is that points??

Comment: in the php code section under `getProducts()` its the last `<td>` to get echo'd

Comment: so `$product_price` variable has that value??

Comment: yes. you can see the example page @ http://mc.athomestudios.net/index.php?page=shop/sell

Comment: Are you wanting the total on initial page load, or after any of the `input` values are changed?

Comment: after the input values for `quantity` are changed

Comment: (1) what is `.on("input"` in `$("input[name='quantity']").on("input", function(){`? shouldn't that be `.on("change"`? (2) why are you doing `$(element).text()` in `total += parseInt($(element).text());`. shouldn't that be `$(this).text()`?

Comment: Also, I don't see where you call `adding()`.

Comment: @Sean that javascript code came from Arg0n over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33960209/trying-to-get-total-amount-based-on-user-input

Answer (score 0):

Just add the value in php

```
<?php 

function getProducts() {
    $total = 0;//           <---------- this line
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM `oc_product` ORDER BY `model` ASC';
    $params = array();
    $results = dataQuery($query,$params);
    foreach ($results as $result) {
        $product_id = $result['product_id'];
        $product_name = getProductName($product_id);
        $product_image = 'shop/image/'.$result['image'];
        $product_price = 1;
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td width="15px"><img src="'.$product_image.'" width="10px" height="10px" /></td>';
        echo '<td width="200px">'.$product_name.'</td>';
        echo '<td width="150px"><input type="number" value="0" min="0" max="3456" name="quantity" /></td>';
        echo '<td width="200px" align="center" class="price" data-product-price="'.$product_price.'">0</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        $total += $product_price;//         <------- this line
    }
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='points' value='$total'";
}
```

Print the value like this

```
<tr>
   <td align="right" colspan="3"><strong>Total:</strong></td>
   <td id="Total" align="center"></td>   <---- leave empty
</tr>
```

Now in script

```
$("#Total").html($("#points").val() + " Points");
```

Comment: so then how would this output to be in the last row of my table?

Comment: `Notice: Undefined variable: total in /customers/b/4/a/athomestudios.net/httpd.www/mc/catalog/view/default/pages/shop/sell.php on line 56`

Comment: I don't think its going to be possible to output the total via mysql, that's why I was looking at javascript to do it. The quantity depicts the total points for that 1 item, and that is all taken care of using javascript. Then I tried the second javascript function to add up all the rows but it prints out 0 no matter what.

Comment: its possible... is it ok if we get the value using hidden fields??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju your `$total` is being defined inside the `function getProducts()`, so it is not accessible outside that function. This is a basic variable scope issue - http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: @rackemup420 i have edited the answer, you can check that.

Comment: @Sean ya i got it, so i have user a hidden field, or OP can make use of global variable.

Comment: still does nothing, check the webpage i posted, i updated the code there and it still doesn't work.

Comment: This isn't going to work as `$product_price` contains a base price and not the actual total that is being calculated in the `points earned` column. The `points earned` column gets populated by the javascript i posted above.